# Java different approaches to handle if null then new

Tags: java, null

Okay, I've got a question about handling nulls. This question can be heavily based upon opinion, therefore I'm going to ask about pro's and cons.

Let's say I've got a function that can return null, or a JSONArray. I always want a JSONArray, so I want it to create an empty one if the function's result is null.

Currently I've got the following approach:

```
jsonArray = jsonArray==null?new JSONArray():jsonArray;
```

I like this approach as it's one line, and pretty clear what it does. This does lead me to the question though, is this efficient? I've got the idea that now it'll execute `jsonArray = jsonArray` while not needed. Though this does seem to save one jump you would have with an `if (jsonArray == null)`

What are the advantages of different ways of handling nulls?

Comment: Unfortunately `JSONArray` is mutable, otherwise you could use the same empty instance for every case where you replace `null` with an empty one. But I wouldn't think it will make much difference in practice, not unless you have all other parts of your application tuned to maximum performance.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the cost of assigning `jsonArray` to itself is in any way significant? (Note that it's not *really* saving a jump, in that you've still got a condition, just expressed in a different way...0

Comment: Why not just make it so that the method _cannot_ return null in the first place?

Comment: @fge No, that would be too easy.

Comment: @fge The function is used more general than just in one case. This means that in some cases I actually want to get a null, instead of an empty array.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg Please make mention that above fact in your question.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg Now **that** is a bad idea. Either use `null`s everywhere you mean `null`, or not at all. Having a mixture of methods that may or may not accept/emit nulls is a testing nightmare.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not. I would not know how to test this, to be honest. That is why I am asking this question. It might indeed make no difference, as mentioned in my post. "I have the idea that". It is an extra operation, and therefore will have extra cost, if this extra cost is significant... It will be when executed often enough.

Comment: @biziclop I know it is, which is why I'm cautious about it in my documentation. However, for my question it does not really make a difference. If I would not want this kind of behaviour, I'd still have to add such an "if", just that it'd be inside the function instead of after the function call.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg When you think about it, even if it is executed billions of times, the extra cost will be insignificant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Java 8's `Optional` class?  This is an object wrapper that lets you handle null in a functional way.

For example, if you have a method `public JSONArray getArray()` that you want to always return something other than null, you can use your code.  Using Optional, it would change to this:

```
public Optional<JSONArray> getArray() {
    // jsonArray comes from somewhere
    return Optional.ofNullable(jsonArray);
}
```

In cases where jsonArray is null, the optional will be empty; in cases where it's not null, it will contain jsonArray.

You can then replace null checks with behaviour dictated by the optional.  Instead of

```
JSONArray array = getArray();
if (array != null) {
    // do something
}
```

you replace it with

```
getArray().ifPresent(array -> // do something);
```

This means you don't need to create empty JSONArrays, or Lists, or Sets, or Strings, or whatever.  In cases where the wrapped object is actually null, a singleton Optional is returned from `Optional.ofNullable`, further reducing overhead.

If you still want to take a classic approach, that's possible too.  Since `if (option == null)` should always evaluate to `false` (if you return null instead of an Optional, you kind of miss the point!), you woud use `if (option.isPresent())`.

If you're not using Java 8, you can either write your own Optional or use a third-party library such as Guava.

EDIT: Non-Java 8 solutions

### Solution 1

Use something like Guava - take a look at http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html

### Solution 2

Write your own!  In this implementation, `Supplier`, `Consumer` and `Predicate` are interfaces that return, accept or test an object.

```
public abstract class Option<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private static final Option NONE = new None();

    private Option() {
        // no-op
    }

    public static <T> Option<T> of(T t) {
        return t == null ? NONE : new Some<T>(t);
    }

    public static <T> Option<T> empty() {
        return NONE;
    }

    public abstract T get();

    public abstract T orElse(T fallback);

    public abstract T orElse(Supplier<T> supplier);

    public abstract <E extends Exception> T orThrow(Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E;

    public abstract boolean isPresent();

    public abstract Option<T> filter(Predicate<T> predicate);

    public abstract void ifPresent(Consumer<T> consumer);

    public abstract <O> Option<O> ifPresent(Function<T, O> function);

    private static final class Some<T> extends Option<T> {

        private final T value;

        private Some(final T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public T orElse(final T fallback) {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public T orElse(final Supplier<T> supplier) {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public <E extends Exception> T orThrow(final Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPresent() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Option<T> filter(final Predicate<T> predicate) {
            return predicate.test(value) ? this
                                         : NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public void ifPresent(final Consumer<T> consumer) {
            consumer.consume(value);
        }

        @Override
        public <O> Option<O> ifPresent(final Function<T, O> function) {
            return Option.of(function.apply(value));
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return Collections.singletonList(value).iterator();
        }
    }

    private static final class None<T> extends Option<T> {
        @Override
        public T get() {
            throw new IllegalStateException("value not defined");
        }

        @Override
        public T orElse(final T fallback) {
            return fallback;
        }

        @Override
        public T orElse(final Supplier<T> supplier) {
            return supplier.get();
        }

        @Override
        public <E extends Exception> T orThrow(final Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
            throw exceptionSupplier.get();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPresent() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Option<T> filter(final Predicate<T> predicate) {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void ifPresent(final Consumer<T> consumer) {
            // no-op
        }

        @Override
        public <O> Option<O> ifPresent(final Function<T, O> function) {
            return NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return Collections.<T>emptyList().iterator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply `JSONArray arr = getArray().orElse(new JSONArray());`

Comment: This would be much worthy if you could state the solution you see for previous Java version.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan coming up

Comment: +1 for `Optional`. But it might be worth mentioning that this has more overhead than the `if (x == null) {` approach.

Comment: @sdgfsdh This is not an issue of performance, but code design. In the grand scheme of things, it doesn't matter which one you use performance-wise, since the real hotspots are elsewhere.